# Xamarin iOS - UITextView passes the area limit

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uitextview

I have a little problem.

I created a `UITextView` on a `ViewController` and added a shadow effect on him.
It worked, but when the `UITextView` scrolls the text, it passes the `UITextView` area limit.

I noted that this happens when the `TextView.Layer.MasksToBounds` are set on `false`.
But, if I change to `true`, the shadow does not work any more.

That's the code of my `UITextView`

```
UITextView TextView = new UITextView(new RectangleF(10, 50, (float)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width - 20, 300));
TextView.Layer.ShadowColor = UIColor.DarkGray.CGColor;
TextView.Layer.ShadowOpacity = 1.0f;
TextView.Layer.ShadowRadius = 2.0f;
TextView.Layer.ShadowOffset = new SizeF(0f, 1f);
TextView.Layer.MasksToBounds = false;
TextView.Layer.CornerRadius = 2.0f;
View.AddSubview(TextView);
```

With TextView.Layer.MasksToBounds = false:

[image]

Now the same code again, but changed the `TextView.Layer.MasksToBounds = true`.

[image]

Does anyone know how can I keep the shadow and not have this problem anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new `UIView` with the same dimensions as the `UITextView`, and apply the shadow to the new view:

```
var textView = new UITextView(new RectangleF(10, 50, (float)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width - 20, 300));
var shadowView = new UIView(textView.Frame);
shadowView.Layer.ShadowColor = UIColor.DarkGray.CGColor;
shadowView.Layer.ShadowOpacity = 1.0f;
shadowView.Layer.ShadowRadius = 2.0f;
shadowView.Layer.ShadowOffset = new SizeF(0f, 1f);
shadowView.Layer.MasksToBounds = false;
shadowView.Layer.CornerRadius = 2.0f;
View.AddSubview(shadowView);
View.AddSubview(textView);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is the iOS expected behavior. If you don't set MaskToBounds then anything outside the bounds will be visible, in this case the text, but if you set MaskToBounds to true, then the shadows will disappear as they're outside the bounds.

The most simple way to solve this is to add the text field to another view and then make this new view to cast the shadow.